# In wix, using vbscript, how do I write to the log file?

Tags: vbscript, wix

I am trying the following inside a customaction:

```
Session.Log("GetOfficeBitness =" & Session.Property("OfficeBitness"))
```

And I am getting the error:

> Error 1720. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A
>   script required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact
>   your support personnel or package vendor. Custom action
>   GetOfficeBitness script error -2146827850, Microsoft VBScript runtime
>   error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Session.Log'
>   Line 39, Column 9,   MSI (c) (FC:94) [05:51:13:621]: Product: Windward
>   Report Designer 32-bit -- Error 1720. There is a problem with this
>   Windows Installer package. A script required for this install to
>   complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package
>   vendor. Custom action GetOfficeBitness script error -2146827850,
>   Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property
>   or method: 'Session.Log' Line 39, Column 9,

How can I write to the log inside my script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Installer Deferred execution - how can we log the custom actions running in deferred mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572168/windows-installer-deferred-execution-how-can-we-log-the-custom-actions-running)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add a log to my vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15908693/692942)

Comment: @Lankymart I don't think so because my vbscript is in a wix file. I haven't found a way to have a stand-alone vbscript in the wix file that I can then call from another script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WIX installer execute vbscript from CustomAction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51947460/692942)

Answer (score 2):

> ***Logging***: Please try to read **Robert Dickau's** [**MSI Tip: Writing to the Log File from a Custom Action**](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/msi_writing_to_the_log_file.pdf). In essence
> something like this:
>
> ```
> option explicit
> dim inst, rec
> set inst = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
> set rec=inst.CreateRecord (2)
> rec.StringData(1) = "Logging call from " & property("CustomActionData")
> Session.Message &H04000000, rec
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ***WiX Sample***: I just remembered that I put a sample for this on github: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXVBScriptWriteToLog

---

***Tip***: [Here is a bunch of WiX / MSI links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) on all kinds of topics centering around debugging.

---

***Links***:

- [Enable installation logs for MSI installer without any command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890) (about MSI logging in general)
- [Windows Installer Deferred execution - how can we log the custom actions running in deferred mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572168/windows-installer-deferred-execution-how-can-we-log-the-custom-actions-running/57573250#57573250)

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find it - I kept looking for some kind of Session.Log() call. Is there a way to put all that in its own script in the wix that other scripts can call? Then I can call Log("hi there") when I need to log. ???

Comment: I don't use VBScript for anything but testing when it comes to custom actions (it is great for testing though - no runtime requirements and very simple). Could you use [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57573250/129130) or [preferably C++ instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54929785/129130) for your custom actions? Then you can call the logging in a separate function quite easily. I suppose you could use some VBScript hacks too, but the feature set is limited. [C++ custom actions are  actually easier to debug once you know how to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52880033/129130).

Comment: If I was starting from scratch - yes. But there's a ton of VB in this and I just need to add some logging to it.

Comment: Hmm, I have honestly never tried to keep all code in a single VBScript file and call functions from within each custom action sub or function. Not sure if that would work to be honest. When I have more than basic needs I abandon VBScript. How much code are we talking about? VBScript is very hard to debug in MSI. Could you run the code on application launch instead? Or is this for addins? [Custom actions are very error prone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46179779/129130).

Comment: It's not even a single vbs file, it's all short scripts inline in custom actions. I may just be stuck having to do all that code each time.

Comment: Can you log to the system's main event log? I suppose you have code for that in VBScript and it failed from within a custom action? [Sample here](https://www.vbsedit.com/scripts2/logs/eventlog/scr_1410.asp). It showed up in my system's *`"Program"`* log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208377/discussion-between-stein-asmul-and-david-thielen).

Comment: I appreciate all the help you've provided. But I'm just going to do this the hard way. It's 5 log messages so not a big deal to do it the hard way. You have convinced me though to put in a JIRA ticket to redo all this using C# when we get a chance. Thank you very much - this was all very helpful.

Comment: OK, great. C# is better, the best is C++ - nothing like native, down-to-the-metal, minimum dependency and easily debuggable code. C++ itself as a language is obviously a nightmare though - .NET API is way easier to use and more accessible to learn & use.